# What is the difference between CsrfViewMiddleware and enforce_csrf?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf, csrf-token

I am trying to apply CSRF token in Django.

I am applying csrf token using middleware and custom authentication.

But I think I'm doing the same process twice.

Because the value of csrf_token from cookie and response is different.

Is it okay to apply+check csrf token by middleware only?

1. MiddleWare

   **settings.py**

   ```
   CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True  # CSRF cookie enabled only Https server
   CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True  # CSRF stored in http only cookie
   CSRF_TESTED_ORIGINS = [
   "http://localhost:8000"
   ]
   CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"  # Samesite "Lax" - Protection against csrf attacks

   MIDDLEWARE = [
   ...
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
   ]
   ```
2. enforce csrf during authentication

   **authenticate.py** (I have set CustomAuthentication as DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES)

   ```
   from rest_framework_simplejwt import authentication as jwt_authentication
   from django.conf import settings
   from rest_framework import authentication, exceptions as rest_exceptions


   def enforce_csrf(request):
       check = authentication.CSRFCheck(request)
       reason = check.process_view(request, None, (), {})
       print(check, reason)
       print(request.META)
       if reason:
           raise rest_exceptions.PermissionDenied('CSRF Failed: %s' % reason)


   class CustomAuthentication(jwt_authentication.JWTAuthentication):
       def authenticate(self, request):
           header = self.get_header(request)

           if header is None:
               raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE']) or None
           else:
               raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)

           if raw_token is None:
               return None

           validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
           enforce_csrf(request)
           return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
   ```

   **loginView**

   ```
   response["X-CSRFToken"] = request.COOKIES.get("csrftoken")
   ```

You can check the django csrf documentation here.
[django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/csrf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to enforce CSRF protection twice in your code.
Django `CsrfViewMiddleware` is responsible for checking the validity of the CSRF token for incoming requests and for adding the CSRF token to outgoing responses.

In your custom authentication class, you are using the `enforce_csrf` function to check the validity of the CSRF token. The same check is already being performed by the `CsrfViewMiddleware`.

You can remove the enforce_csrf function from your custom authentication class and rely on the `CsrfViewMiddleware` to enforce CSRF protection.

Also, in your loginView code, you are setting the `X-CSRFToken` header to the value of the csrftoken cookie. This header is not necessary because the `CsrfViewMiddleware` sets the `X-CSRFToken` header in the response automatically.